# Local push notification by GPS position

Tags: ios, gps, push-notification, core-location

I have a simple question about iOS, GPS Location and push notification.

Is possible in iOS to send a local push notification when the device is near of a specific GPS position?

Comment: I not found any good documentation about this..Is possible to suggest me something

Comment: wait i will create demo kind app and give you soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code for ViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    NSString* lastNotification;
}

@end
```

Following code for ViewController.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    lastNotification = @"";
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark -User Actions
- (IBAction)startLocaingMe:(id)sender{
    [self startLocationReporting];
}

#pragma mark - Location Metods

- (void)startLocationReporting {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;//or whatever class you have for managing location
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

// Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power
    CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
    NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0) {
        [self showNotificationIfDistanceIs100:location];
    }
}

// this delegate method is called if an error occurs in locating your current location
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"locationManager:%@ didFailWithError:%@", manager, error);
}

- (CLLocationDistance)distanceBetweenTwoPoints:(CLLocation*) location1 andSecond:(CLLocation*) location2{
    CLLocationDistance distance = [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2];
    return distance;
}

-(CLLocation*)House{
    CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:23.030064 longitude:72.546193];
    return loc;
}

-(CLLocation*)passportOffice{
    CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:23.032034 longitude:72.549999];
    return loc;
}

-(CLLocation*)ldCollageBusStand{
    CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:23.032515 longitude:72.549307];
    return loc;
}

-(void)showNotificationIfDistanceIs100:(CLLocation*) location{
    if ([self distanceBetweenTwoPoints:location andSecond:[self House]] <= 100) {
        [self setLocalNotificaion:@"Your are 100 meter form House"];
    }else if ([self distanceBetweenTwoPoints:location andSecond:[self passportOffice]] <= 100){
        [self setLocalNotificaion:@"Your are 100 meter form Passport Office"];
    }else if ([self distanceBetweenTwoPoints:location andSecond:[self ldCollageBusStand]] <= 100){
        [self setLocalNotificaion:@"Your are 100 meter form Ld Collage Bus Stand"];
    }

}

-(void)setLocalNotificaion:(NSString*)msg{
    if ([lastNotification isEqualToString:msg] != YES) {
        lastNotification = msg;
        UILocalNotification *futureAlert;
        futureAlert = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        [futureAlert setAlertBody:msg];
        futureAlert.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
        futureAlert.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:futureAlert];
    }
}

@end
```

You can change location Long/Lati and getting the Localnotification

May this thinks lot helpful

**-------EDITED---------**

[image]

Comment: I created a simple project with your code but, when I send the app to background I not see anything.. I changed the Lat and Long coordinate, I added a breakpoint into showNotificationIfDistanceIs100 method and when the app is active it stops at that point..Have I to change something?

Comment: ok, now I see the local notifications also when the app is in background. I have a question,
Looking at your code I understand that the local notifications are only added only when the app is active. If the app is in the background and I'm close to home the app can not add a new notification. Is correct this? Is possible to adds Local notifications when the app is also in background?

Comment: wait while i implement those code and inform you ASAP

Comment: @Safari please check updated screen shot and implement in your project 
if you satisfy with my answer then please upvote or approve my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `LocationManager` instance and get notified about location updates in the following method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
   // CLLocation object will be the content of the array locations
}
```

You can post `UILocalNotification` based on your requirements.

Comment: do you mean `CLLocationManagerDelegate` rather than `LocationManager`?

Comment: CLLocationManagerDelegate is must for invoking the method. Location manager should be instantiated for starting location update.